# C++ как работают std::istream::read, std::ostream::write?

Tags: c++, fstream

Я не совсем понимаю как работают read и write, а именно как он берёт значения, из, допустим, структуры и затем записывает их из файла в другую структуру. Вот, к примеру код:

```
struct Write
{
    int x_x = 5;
    int y_y = 10;
};

struct Read
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void binaryFileWrite(const std::string &fileName)
{
    Write write;
    std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        file.write((char*)(&write), sizeof(Write));
        file.close();
    }
}

void binaryFileRead(const std::string &fileName)
{
    Read read;
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&read), sizeof(Read));

        std::cout << read.x << " " << read.y << " " << std::endl;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

`file.write((char*)(&write), sizeof(Write));`
Оно поочередно берёт значения из структуры, а именно x_x и y_y, затем записывает их в файл, а когда читает из файла `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&read), sizeof(Read));`, то точно так же просто поочерёдно их записывает в каждую ячейку другой структуры? Я просто не совсем понимаю как оно осознает что куда записать. Можно усложнить ситуацию, и, к примеру, придумать другую структуру или класс, где не 2 значения int, а 2 значения char и 1 int, тут как оно работает? если же я изначально все правильно понял и оно просто-напросто поочерёдно копирует и так же поочерёдно записывает в процедурном порядке, но всё равно хочется услышать другой ответ, а не опираться на собственные догадки.
А ещё есть вопрос касательно того, есть ли разница между `reinterpret_cast<char *>` и `(char *)`

Comment: ты когда записал структуру в файл. Для начала надо представить как эта структура выглядит в памяти. В ней последовательно лежат два инта. 8 байт. Программа взяла эти 8 байт и записала. Потом когда считывание. Она взяла эти же 8 байт и прочитала. Если размер не совпадет, будет нехорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Структура имеет некоторое представление в памяти. Каждый следующий член, не помеченный аттрибутом `[[no_unique_address]]`, занимает более старший адрес. Из-за требований к выравниванию, может вставляться padding.

Предполагая, что `sizeof(int) == 4`, и `alignof(int) == 4`, эта структура займёт 8 байт памяти:

```
struct Write
{
    int x_x = 5;
    int y_y = 10;
};
```

И эта тоже 8, из-за того, что будет вставляться padding после `char`.

```
struct Write1
{
    int x_x = 5;
    char y_y = 10;
};
```

`write` и `read` не видят определение структуры, они работают с памятью,  интерпретированной как `char*`, т.е. `write` запишет всё целиком, и значения, и padding.

`reinterpret_cast<char *>` - С++ приведение типов, (char *) - С приведение типов. Лучше в С++ использовать `reinterpret_cast<char *>`, он не сделает ничего другого, кроме подмены типов (в частности, не снимет константность), и лучше выделяется.